# Signing a VB.NET application

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

Do I have to sign my VB.NET applications?

I'm getting an error:

```
SignTool reported an error 'Keyset does not exist'
```

But have no interest in signing anything as the project is small and will only be used internally to my department.

I could create a temporary key. But why would I want to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/feb6bbe9-38af-4976-9a68-f1066bf5d23b/) looks like it may help...

Comment: Yes, the new project created a temporary key.
So, I found the old key, and copied it into a common place, so that the new project could also see it.
I then had to uninstall and reinstall the finished system on the client PC.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem...

I went to the Signing tab of "My Project", unchecked and checked the "Sign the ClickOnce Manifests", then "Create Test Certificate".

I saved and then published.  During Publish, it asked me to confirm the new certificate.  "OK"

Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: no, signing is not required. By default your projects are not signed.

Maybe Dave's post will help with the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Signing an assembly with strong name is usually taking place when assembly will be place to `GAC`, so strong name provides safe referencing.

Only assembly manufacturer has specified `public key token`, so making a reference to an assembly from you application while development, you can be sure that the same assembly will be used by user.

So if your application has `GUI`, I think `not`, signing is not required. If it's a `library`, which can be used public, `yes`, sign it.